# Writing to text file with python running on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need to have my python app store store some text on a file that I have already created on a GCS bucket on GAE.

All the documentation I found so far covers more sophisticated examples than my simple use case, and I'm getting disoriented.

All I really want to do is to is to find the equivalent for the following on GCS (including any possible imports necessary to replicate this on GCS):

```
with open("../somedir/somefile.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("appended text")
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant modify files in GCS. Once they are closed thats it. To append I would do this:

```
import cloudstorage
from google.appengine.api import app_identity


bucketName = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        fileName = "/" + bucketName + "/somedir/somefile.txt"

        try:
            with cloudstorage.open(fileName, "r") as gcsFile:
                tempStorage = gcsFile.read()
                tempStorage += "\n"
        except:
            tempStorage = ""

        with cloudstorage.open(fileName, "w") as gcsFile:
            gcsFile.write(tempStorage + "appended text")

        with cloudstorage.open(fileName, "r") as gcsFile:
            output=  gcsFile.read()  
        self.response.out.write(output)
```

Just writing:

```
import cloudstorage
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

bucketName = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
fileName = "/" + bucketName + "/somedir/somefile.txt"

with cloudstorage.open(fileName, "w") as gcsFile:
            gcsFile.write("text")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write or append data to /tmp/file on GAE.
If file is done and no more need to be modified, you can upload the file to GCS which might be more efficient.